# Azure Web Apps deployment fails as it cannot detect an assembly which is already there

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Deploying my web-API application on Azure web apps through VS 2019.
Enabled logging in web.config under /wwwroot folder.

Got the below error:

> Error:   An assembly specified in the application dependencies
> manifest (BuildingBlock.LearningManagement.Category.Api.deps.json) was
> not found:
> package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
> path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
> This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the
> application was published using the following target manifest files:
> aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml

As far as I understand, it cannot find **BuildingBlock.LearningManagement.Category.Api.deps.json** file, but I checked under wwwroot, it is there.
[Kudu Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQifE.png)

Have tried few solutions suggested in [this link](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3215), still the error persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the below solution:
Add a property group to your csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This worked for me fine.